# Is there a way to animate the transition of slides in racket slideshow?

Tags: racket, slideshow

I'm trying to animate the transition between slides to make it look less abrupt. As far as I understand the documentation, the slides should be animated using the play procedure. However, I am having difficulties applying it.

My goal was something like this, where one slide fades out and the next one fades in.

```
#lang slideshow

(require slideshow/play)


(define my-animated-slide
  (animate-slide
   'alts
   (list (list (item "The first slide"))
         (list (item "The second slide"))
         (list (item "The third slide")))))

(play-n my-animated-slide)
```

Is it even possible to animate the transition at all?

Comment: I recommend asking on Racket Discourse instead.

Comment: Invite link for racket discourse https://racket.discourse.group/invites/VxkBcXY7yL

Comment: you may also try asking in #slideshow on Racket Discord.  Invite link https://discord.gg/6Zq8sH5

Comment: @pomidor please let us know if you were successful

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but I found https://github.com/LeifAndersen/slideshow-pretty on GitHub.

From the readme:

> slideshow-pretty
>
> This library adds functionality to make pretty transitions in the
> racket slideshow framework. This library is still under heavy
> development, and will likely break backwards compatibility.
>
> How to install

```
git clone git://github.com/LeifAndersen/slideshow-pretty.git 
cd slideshow 
raco link . 
raco setup slideshow-pretty For users
```

> Inside of a slideshow, use `(require slideshow/pretty)` for the
> transition functions.